# Trouble setting up WebDAV

Tags: iis-7, webdav

Rather than using FTP to access my hosting provider, which I read is un-secure, I'm trying to set up WebDAV (which I've never done before).  I don't see WebDAV in the Actions pane of IIS Manager.

So I found a link at http://www.iis.net/extensions/WebDAV to install it. I'm running Windows 7, so when the Web Platform Installer gave a message that my operating system is not supported, I tried the x64 link from that site. Then I get the message "IIS Version 7.0 is required to use WebDav 7.5 for IIS". That would suggest I didn't install IIS7, which I'm pretty positive I did.

In IIS Manager the Help | About says Version 6.1 (Build 7600) at the top (6.1 makes me think IIS6?) but then at the bottom, it says "Internet Information Services (Version 7.5.7600.16385), which seems to suggest IIS7, right?  Any ideas on how I can get going with WebDAV?  Thanks!

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.com